# update protractor chrome driver to 74

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

**How do I update to 74 version of chromedriver**

normally I would do:

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.46
```

however the following is not working:

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 74.0.3729.6
```

I am on `Protractor Version 5.4.2`
Dont want to upgrade to 6 as API is not yet completed

Log:

```
[16:21:43] E/downloader - undefined
[16:21:43] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_74.0.3729.6.zip
[16:21:43] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_74.0.3729.6.zip
(node:35565) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Invalid filename
(node:35565) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:35565) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[16:21:44] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip.jar
[16:21:44] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip.jar up to date
[16:21:44] I/update - geckodriver: file exists /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.24.0.tar.gz
[16:21:44] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.24.0.tar.gz
[16:21:44] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.24.0
[16:21:44] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.24.0 up to date
```

**[UPDATE - SOLUTION]**

```
npm install -g webdriver-manager@12.1.4
webdriver-manager version
webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: The folder where webdriver-manager downloads your installation package may contain multiple chromdrivers. Try going there and removing them manually and then running your command again. Don't forget about different types of installation - global and local. Let me know if doesn't help

Answer (score 3):

I found a working solution for `protractor 5.4.2`. You need to install `webdriver-manager v12.1.3` and run `npm dedupe`. Then run `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.46`. In my case it didn't work because of `webdriver-manager 12.1.1` installed `selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip.jar` (this version only works with `protractor 6.0.0`) instead of `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar`.

**Old answer**

Only way I found to start it now (30.04.2019) is to start webdriver-manager separately and connect to its instance. It works with `protractor v6.0.0` and `webdriver-manager v12.1.3`.

add this to `protractor.conf.js`:

```
exports.config = {
// ...
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
// ...
}
```

then run `webdriver-manager start` and in another tab `protractor protractor.conf.js`