# Angular 8.x e2e Tests Won't Run

Tags: angular

Generated default setup for app (minus routing) in Angular 8.0.2 using the CLI.

`ng test` works but `ng e2e` does not. The error complains about Chrome.

```
C:\Users\user\my-dream-app>ng e2e
[06:26:10] I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_75.0.3770.8.zip
[06:26:10] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_75.0.3770.8.zip
[06:26:10] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_75.0.3770.8.exe up to date

Date: 2019-06-10T10:26:29.077Z
Hash: d3f131a7889575adf622
Time: 13878ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 9.77 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 248 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 380 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.67 MB [initial] [rendered]
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ?wdm?: Compiled successfully.
[06:26:30] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[06:26:30] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:16131/devtools/browser/84b893db-c880-496e-a908-248c8a756f0a
[06:26:33] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#40}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
[06:26:33] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#40}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\user\my-dream-app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[06:26:33] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I'll admit that I am still learning Angular but upon some googling I thought this issue was [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910242/when-using-protractor-5-4-2-webdriver-manager-downloads-2-46-which-is-not-compa/55911176#55911176) so why is this happening and how do I fix it? My chrome browser version (which shows in about chrome) is Chrome version 74.0.3729.169

Comment: Just to double check, what version of chrome do you have?

Comment: Chrome version 74.0.3729.169

Comment: "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75" 

I'm running 75 myself so try getting it upgraded

Comment: So I'm assuming chrome doesn't auto download updates like firefox?

Comment: It should but I don't know what it's strategy for looking for updates is, I've seen this happen before but don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chromedriver requires a specific version of chrome installed locally so make sure you have the same version of chrome installed locally as the driver uses.

For some reason chrome doesn't upgrade automatically some times but if you go to Help -> about Google Chrome you can see your current version and click the button there to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Manually updated Chrome to latest version, restarted chrome. Now e2e tests work.