# session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75 - while running angular e2e in Concourse

Tags: angular, protractor, concourse, angular-e2e

While executing e2e test in concourse, I'm getting the below error, where it looks like the chromedriver is not getting updated. While similar problems were discussing about chrome version falling behind, in my case, the chrome stable version is getting downloaded as expected (76.0.3809.100). But the chromedriver version thats getting pulled by protractor's webmanager driver is stuck in 2.46.

I tried to manually update the chromedriver from 2.46 to 76.0.3809.12, but it was still falling back to 2.46 during execution.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -u -x

wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

cd git-platformUI/ui

npm install

npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

$(npm bin)/ng e2e --configuration=$CONFIG
```

> [07:33:13] E/launcher - session not created: Chrome version must be
>   between 71 and 75   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388
>   (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux
>   4.15.0-36-generic x86_64) [07:33:13] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome version must be
>   between 71 and 75   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388
>   (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux
>   4.15.0-36-generic x86_64)
>       at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
>       at parseHttpResponse (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
>       at doSend.then.response (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
>       at Function.createSession (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
>       at Function.createSession (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
>       at Direct.getNewDriver (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
>       at Runner.createBrowser (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
>       at q.then.then (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
>       at _fulfilled (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
>       at /tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
>       at runSingle (/tmp/build/357f536d/git-platformUI/ui/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
>   [07:33:13] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

Comment: Have you tried updating webdriver-manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When using Protractor 5.4.2, webdriver-manager downloads 2.46 which is not compatible with Chrome 74](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910242/when-using-protractor-5-4-2-webdriver-manager-downloads-2-46-which-is-not-compa)

Comment: The solution in the above link did not work for me. But the solution in the github issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5289 worked for me.

"postinstall": "cd ./node_modules/protractor && npm i webdriver-manager@latest && cd ../.. && ./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update"

Answer (score 11):

Delete your `node_modules` folder, add the below script to your `package.json` file and  `npm install`. As posted in the comments above and on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5289#issuecomment-517261124)

```
"postinstall": "cd ./node_modules/protractor && npm i webdriver-manager@latest",
```

**Update:**
The above script started breaking on me once the latest version started changed to `webdriver-manager@12.1.7` so I had to be explicit with the version and set it to `12.1.6`:

```
"postinstall": "cd ./node_modules/protractor && npm i webdriver-manager@12.1.6",
```

Comment: Before removing `node_modules` folder, first try runing `cd ./node_modules/protractor && npm i webdriver-manager`... because it worked for me without removing node_modules

Answer (score 6):

Try the below commands:

```
npm install protractor@5.4.2 --save-dev
ng e2e
```

It will work and download the latest chrome driver **chromedriver_78.0.3904.70.zip**.

Comment: protractor is a dev dependency. I think it should be --save-dev

Answer (score 2):

Updated the protractor devDependency to latest (5.4.2) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just installed **a missing package** and reinstall all deps:

```sh
npm i -D webdriver-manager
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

... and run end-to-end tests one more time:

```sh
npm run e2e
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that is why I am here,
I tired everything until below

> npm install chromedriver